# Some Objective-C methods are invisible in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, j2objc

Why this method
`+ (instancetype)arrayWithNSData:(NSData *)data;`

in **j2obj** project

https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/Classes/IOSPrimitiveArray.h#L252

invisible for Swift3?

but the other are visible.
for example this:

`+ (instancetype)newArrayWithBytes:(const jbyte *)buf count:(NSUInteger)count;`

Comment: Are you sure it's invisible? Normal importer rules would convert that to an initializer — look for something like `init(nsData:)` in Xcode's "generated interface" view.

Comment: @rickster , thanks. My fault.

Comment: No worries... converted the comment to an answer so it's more helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory methods in ObjC — that is, class methods that return `instancetype` (or the actual type of the class) and start with the common name of the class — get imported to Swift as initializers.

So a method `+(instancetype)arrayWithSomething:` on a class whose name includes `Array` gets imported as `init(something:)`. In your case, `+arrayWithNSData:` will get imported as `init(nsData:)`. (You might think it'd drop the "NS", since it'll also convert the parameter type from `NSData` to its Swift value type equivalent `Foundation.Data`... but it doesn't.)

To find this and other importer effects, you can see the result for yourself in Xcode by looking at the "Generated Interface" view of your source. Check the related items button at the left of the jump bar, or the assistant editor.

For more details, read about [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID37) in Apple's *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* doc.